# How to find value of one of root elements in xml using XElement? when the root elements have no child elements?

Tags: xml, linq, xelement

I would like to find the value of `errorCode` node using `XElement`. Please advise.

```
<registration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <errorCode>201498</errorCode>
  <errorMessage>XML response de-serialization error.  Details: XML ??(1, 569)?????</errorMessage>
</registration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load the xml into an XElement and call Element method to retrieve value

```
//Load from file location
var errFile = XElement.Load("C:\\YourFile.xml");

//Get Element value from xml
var errorCode = (string)_x.Element("errorCode");
```